# Trigonometric identities with Python and Sympy, tan(A/2) = (sin A )/(1 + cos A)

Tags: python, math, trigonometry, sympy, symbolic-math

I'm not sure how to get Sympy to perform / simplify these types of identities?

It does things like `sin(a + b)`, but doesn't seem to do others (like the one in the title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to try various combinations of simplification functions/methods such as `rewrite` and `simplify`. For example, the following gives the result you want:

```
import sympy as sp

x = sp.var('x', real = True)

f = sp.tan(x/2)

sp.re(f.rewrite(sp.exp).simplify().rewrite(sp.sin)).simplify()
```

> sin(x)/(cos(x) + 1)

Comment: The `sympy.simplify.fu` module has a lot of trig simplifications, but it doesn't seem to have this one yet.